# How to understand and add syllable break in this example?

Tags: nlp, machine-learning

I am new in machine learning and computing probabilities. This is [an example from Lingpipe](http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/demos/tutorial/hyphenation/read-me.html) for adding syllabification in a word by training data.

```
Given a source model p(h) for hyphenated words, and a channel model p(w|h) defined so that p(w|h) = 1 if w is equal to h with the hyphens removed and 0 otherwise. We then seek to find the most likely source message h to have produced message w by:

    ARGMAXh p(h|w) = ARGMAXh p(w|h) p(h) / p(w)
                   = ARGMAXh p(w|h) p(h)         
                   = ARGMAXh s.t. strip(h)=w p(h)

where we use strip(h) = w to mean that w is equal to h with the hyphenations stripped out (in Java terms, h.replaceAll(" ","").equals(w)). Thus with a deterministic channel, we wind up looking for the most likely hyphenation h according to p(h), restricting our search to h that produce w when the hyphens are stripped out.
```

I do not understand how to use it to build a syllabification model.

If there is a training set containing:

```
a bid jan
a bide
a bie
a bil i ty
a bim e lech
```

How to have a model that will syllabify words? I mean what to be computed in order to find possible syllable breaks of a new word.

First compute what? then compute what? Can you please be specific with example?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The method** described in the article is based on a statistical law allowing to compute the *correct* value observing a *noisy* value. In other words, non-syllabified word is *noisy* or *incorrect*, like `picnic`, and the goal is finding a probably *correct* value, which is `pic-nic`.

[Here](https://class.coursera.org/nlp/lecture/preview_view?lecture_id=22_) is an excellent video lesson on very this topic (scroll to 1:25, but the whole set of lectures worth watching).

This method is specifically useful for word delimiting, but some use it for syllabification as well. Chinese language has space delimiters only for logical constructs, but most words follow each other with no delimiters. However, each character is a syllable, no exception.

There are other languages that have more complicated grammar. For instance, Thai has no spaces between the words, but each syllable may be constructed from several symbols, e.g. `สวัสดี` -> `ส-วัส-ดี`. Rule-based syllabification may be hard but possible.

**As per English**, I would not bother with [Markov chains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain) and [N-grams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram) and instead just use several simple rules that give pretty good match ratio (not perfect, however):

1. Two consonants between two vowels `VCCV` - split between them `VC-CV` as in c**of-fe**e, p**ic-ni**c, **except** the "cluster consonant" that represents a single sound: m**eth-o**d, R**o-che**ster, h**ang-o**ut
2. Three or more consonants between the vowels `VCCCV` - split keeping the blends together as in m**on-ste**r or ch**ild-re**n *(this seems the most difficult as you cannot avoid a dictionary)*
3. One consonant between two vowels `VCV` - split after the first vowel `V-CV` as in b**a-co**n, **a-ri**d
4. The rule above also has an exception based on blends: co**ur-a**ge, pl**ay-ti**me
5. Two vowels together `VV` - split between, except they represent a "cluster vowel": p**o-e**m, but gla**cier**, earl-**ier**

I would start with the "main" rules first, and then cover them with "guard" rules preventing cluster vowels and consonants to be split. Also, there would be an obvious guard rule to prevent a single consonant to become a syllable. When done, I would have added another guard rule based on a dictionary.

Comment: thank you so much for how to split word into possible syllables. Now I have a rough idea of how to use linguistic rule to do it as you explained. Your suggested link is also helpful. This task seems not so easy as there may be a lot of exceptions or irregularities in pronunciations. Can you suggest or comment on rule-based and machine-learning based approaches to coping with splitting word into syllables?

Comment: Thank you for your appreciation of my response. I have never developed syllabification tools for English, but I did this for Thai. Algorithmically, it looks straightforward: **(1)** get a plain list of `Word|PunctuationMark|Space`; **(2)** For each Word, get a list of *possible* break positions; **(3)** Eliminate some positions by guard rules. And another thought. It is well possible there are free libraries for Delphi that do the job. Sorry I cannot give more specific answer. If you don't mind of functional approach, you may use `Haskell` and `parsec` or `F#` and `fParsec`.